# rails, associated field not saving on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to save projects with assignees, well, assigned to it. All fields get saved, except the 'assignee' field, which is an associated field.

```rb
# app/models/project.rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_many   :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :assignees, through: :assignments, source: :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :adversaries, -> { adversaries }, class_name: 'Contact'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients,     -> { clients },     class_name: 'Contact'
end
```

```rb
# app/models/assignment.rb
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```rb
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many   :owned_projects, foreign_key: :owner_id, class_name: 'Project', dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :activities
  has_many   :deadlines
  has_many   :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :projects, through: :assignments
end
```

```rb
# app/models/contact.rb
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

  scope :get_role,    -> (str) { includes(:role).where("contact_roles.label = '#{str}'").references(:contact_roles) }
  scope :clients,     ->       { get_role('client') }
  scope :adversaries, ->       { get_role('adversary') }
end
```

```rb
# app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: "Project was successfully created." }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  
  private
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:label, :reference, :status, :description, :owner_id, :project_category_id, assignee: [:id])
    end
end
```

```html
# app/views/projects/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: project, local: true, class: 'box') do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :assignee_id %>
  <%= form.collection_select(:assignee_id, User.all.order(role: :desc, last_name: :asc), :id, :friendly_name, { include_hidden: false }, { size: 6, required: true, multiple: true, id: :project_assignee_id }) %>
<% end %>
```

And here's the relevant terminal output:

```sh
Started POST "/en/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-06-19 15:43:53 +0200
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"r3ayqmMUFEh93KKhmqJ1VEYeF90QxpFOZiHwgZ0WEeqZM/DEQsI9tpJP8CwFqH0xBF4TZlQ5++Q6o6wt2hRkRA==", "project"=>{"label"=>"asdasdasd", "owner_id"=>"3", "project_category_id"=>"1", "description"=>"asdasdasd", "status"=>"active", "reference"=>"asdasd", "assignee_id"=>["3", "2"]}, "commit"=>"Créer projet", "locale"=>"en"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: :assignee_id
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "projects" ("label", "reference", "status", "description", "owner_id", "project_category_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["label", "asdasdasd"], ["reference", "asdasd"], ["status", 1], ["description", "asdasdasd"], ["owner_id", 3], ["project_category_id", 1], ["created_at", "2021-06-19 13:43:53.565072"], ["updated_at", "2021-06-19 13:43:53.565072"]]
   (0.3ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/en/projects/289
Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

The unpermitted parameter is also quite cryptic, since I've tried most of all the variations I've found online...

Any ideas on how to proceed? Or even just a link to a clear tutorial on the issue?

**EDIT:**

Same issue, but maybe clearer code:

```html
# app/views/projects/_form.html.erb
<%= form.label :assignees %>
<%= form.collection_select(:assignees, User.lawyers.order(role: :desc, last_name: :asc), :id, :friendly_name, { include_hidden: false }, { size: 6, required: true, multiple: true, id: :project_assignees }) %>
```

```rb
# app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:label, :reference, :status, :description, :owner_id, :project_category_id, assignees: [:id])
    end
```

This now clears the unpermitted parameter issue, but the 'assignee' field is still not saved:

```sh
Started POST "/en/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-06-19 16:09:40 +0200
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XHqUoeH4o6XTOTlRPkNebIIhmJw6dgitxTnBtydUfvCvbCVNzNJx9dmMwA1UpSZn3FdVDjeJ21fNhtUP9YA89w==", "project"=>{"label"=>"aasdf", "owner_id"=>"3", "project_category_id"=>"1", "description"=>"asdasd", "status"=>"active", "reference"=>"", "assignees"=>["9"]}, "commit"=>"Créer projet", "locale"=>"en"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "projects" ("label", "reference", "status", "description", "owner_id", "project_category_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["label", "aasdf"], ["reference", ""], ["status", 1], ["description", "asdasd"], ["owner_id", 3], ["project_category_id", 1], ["created_at", "2021-06-19 14:09:40.963949"], ["updated_at", "2021-06-19 14:09:40.963949"]]
   (0.3ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/en/projects/296
Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

Comment: I believe you need to include a line like `accepts_nested_attributes_for :assignees` in your `Project` model. That declaration tells Rails that when saving parameters for the `Project` model, if assignee attributes are passed through the `:assignees_attributes` key, those should be used towards creating/updating assignees. This is explained well in [this article](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, that's still not it...

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `assignee_ids=` setter [thats generated by the `has_many`  macro](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Collection+associations+-28one-to-many+-2F+many-to-many-29):

```
<%= 
form.collection_select(
   :assignee_ids,
   User.lawyers.order(role: :desc, last_name: :asc), # query should be moved to controller
   :id, 
   :friendly_name, 
   { include_hidden: false }, 
   { size: 6, required: true, multiple: true, id: :project_assignees }
) 
%>
```

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project)
        .permit(
          :label, :reference, :status, :description, 
          :owner_id, :project_category_id, 
          assignee_ids: [] # permits an array of ids
        )
end
```

Note that nested attributes is not required here which is a very common misconception. If you just want to assign a relation and create/destroy the join rows implicitly then you just need to use the `_ids` setter/getter and Rails will take care of it for you.

Nested attributes is only required if you need to explicitly create the join rows with additional attributes that describe the relation between the two entities. For example if you need to add a "role" field to assignments that describes what the assignees role in the project is.

Answer (score -1):

You want to create a new record of `assignments` which is the joint table between users and projects while creating a new project. This means you need a so-called nested form. In order to achieve this you need `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `fields_for` helpers. The code snippets can be a start but you should check here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms for your case where you have a many-to-many relationship.

In your projects model:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many   :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :assignees, through: :assignments, source: :user
  ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assignments
end
```

Then in your form:

```
<%= form_with(model: project, local: true, class: 'box') do |form| %>
...
   <%= f.fields_for :assignments do |assignments_form| %>
      <%= assignments_form.input :user_id, collection: User.lawyers.order(role: :desc, last_name: :asc) %>
    <% end %>
...
<% end %>
```

Your controller needs changes in #new and in project params

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def new 
     2.times { @project.assignments.build }
  end

  def create
   ...
  end
  
  private
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:label, :reference, :status, :description, :owner_id, :project_category_id, assignment_attributes: [:user_id])
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, though I'm not sure I entirely understand it. There is an arbitrary amount of assignees which get selected in the collection_select (with multiple: true), so why build precisely two assignments?

Comment: That was just a start, you probably want to add a little plus button that creates more fields to select more assignes later with some JS - but it's always good to make it work with a few first since you had problems even saving it into the DB

Comment: This isn't quite correct. If you just want to implicitly create the join rows you can just do it with the `_ids=` setter. Its only if you want to add additional attributes to the join table (like say for example a role) that you need nested attributes.